# Error Number: 2006, MySQL server has gone away codeigniter sql query

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and to run my query, I am getting this error when i tried to fetch new order there is only 2 or 3 small translations to insert in database. I am using shared hosting on hostgator so i cannot change Max_packet size. (Current set max allowed packet - 16,777,216)

This query i am using -

```
foreach($data_orders as $key=>$value){
    $order_id=trim($value['order_id']);
    $amount_paid=trim($value['amount_paid']);

    $query = $this->db->query("select * from ama_orders 
                              where order_id='".$order_id."' 
                              and amount_paid LIKE  '".$amount_paid."'");  
    // Getting error on this line
    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        unset($data_orders[$key]);      
    }
}
```

and another error i am getting on this code

```
$sql_check= "SELECT order_status from ama_orders where order_id='$check_order_id'";
$query = $this->db->query($sql_check); // Getting error on this line
$ordertemp = array();
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    $ordertemp = $query->result_array();
    if($ordertemp[0]['order_status']=='Unshipped'){
        $update_sql= "UPDATE ama_orders SET order_status='Dispatched'
                     where order_id='$check_order_id'";
        $this->db->query($update_sql); // And Getting error on this line
     }
 }
```

If any body know what i am doing wrong. Please help me with this query.

Comment: What error? Is it asking for breakfast?

Comment: I formatted your code for you, please learn how to do so your self before posting another question. Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can try and disable persistent connections in the database.php config (supplied the fact that you don't require them) - which is sometimes a cause of this error:

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

See https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html for more information